# Migrating OAuth client setup from Spring boot 1.5.9 to 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a spring boot REST api application with OAuth2 spring security in place. Gradle configuration:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.1.RELEASE")
```

The `Application` class is annotated with `@EnableResourceServer` to authenticate each request with OAuth2. The OAuth provider is a custom proprietary one and the `application.yml` file is setup according to [1.5.9 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server) as follows:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: client-id-1
      clientSecret: client-secret-1
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8082/uaa/user
```

In the [latest spring boot 2.0 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/htmlsingle/#_client) I have noticed that OAuth2 clients now need to be configured differently in `application.yml`. I have tried this configuration:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        client1:
          clientId: client-id-1
          clientSecret: client-secret-1
      provider: provider1
    provider:
      provider1:
        userInfoUri: http://localhost:8082/uaa/user
```

But, when sending a request with a valid OAuth token, the configuration is not applied and the REST api responds with 401 - invalid token.

Does anyone know exactly how to configure the client in `application.yml`?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I looked at the [recent docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_client), and it seems things have changed quite a bit.

Comment: @RegisteredUser No, I haven't. I am still using boot 1.5.9 until some more clarity is added to the 2.0 documentation. I think some example code would be helpful in this case.

Comment: I have created a small example application, but for some reason, it ends up using basic authentication

Comment: @RegisteredUser Interesting, in my case it actually uses the OAuth2 filter but it can't find the registered provider to authenticate the token. Maybe we could create a simple test application on GitHub to play around.

Comment: I got the google OAuth working. [Code here](https://github.com/InfiniteCoder/SpringBoot2OAuth2) [Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) and [Blog post here](https://infinitecoder.github.io/2017-12-24-how-to-use-google-oauth-2-0-in-spring-boot-2-0/) 

My guess is your issue is probably with dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @RegisteredUser, I will give it a try. In my case I also need to register a custom provider since my Oauth2 provider is not one of the social ones from the framework.